# Repeating user input and storing values for later

Tags: python

I have gone from 0 to python 3 in a couple of days, however, I am stuck and would appreciate some help

I had to design a program to calculate radioactive decay (which was a big task for me)

here

```
import sys
import math, numpy #importing math and scinece packages for use
import matplotlib as plt #importing graph package and renaming

#Printing welcome message
print ("this program calcualtes the amount of isotope left after a given time\n")


#Defining variables and setting an users input equal to the variable
isotope = str(input("\nWhat isotope are we investigating?"))

#wrapping the float values input from the user around error catching code, forcing user to use numbers only's'
while True:
  try:  
   iso_HL = float(input("\nand how long is it's half life, in seconds please"))
  except:
   print "Oooops, please use numbers only\n"
   continue
  else:
   break

while True:
  try:
    iso_0 = float(input("\nGive me the initial amount of isotope for calculation, in grams"))
  except:
    print "Oooops, please use numbers only\n"
    continue
  else:
    break

while True:
  try:
    iso_ET = float(input("\ni'll need an elasped time to work with, again, in seconds please"))
  except:
    print "Oooops, please use numbers only\n"
    continue
  else:
    break

#The equation to calculate the amount of isotope left after an elasped time
#is P=P_0e^-ln(2)(t/T) where P is the amount of isotope remaining, P_0 is the initial
#amount of isotope, t is the elapsed time and T is the halflife

#creating variables for the user returned calculation
Log2 = math.log(2)
HLTimeCalc = iso_ET/iso_HL

#defining a function to calculate the halflife and return the result
def HalfLife_EQ(initial, Halflife):
  return int(initial * math.exp((-(Log2))*Halflife))

#setting the result variable to equal the function with arguments  
result = HalfLife_EQ(iso_0, HLTimeCalc)

#NOTE: I realize this is a slightly longer way of achieving the outcome, but ive enjoyed learning
#how to use functions and return them, so ive kept it in.

#printing the result variable
print "\nthe isotope of ", isotope, "will have ", result, "grams left after", iso_ET, "seconds"
print "\n Do you want to calculate another isotopes halflife"
```

but now I have to try and get the next two requirements which are

> 6. The program should then repeat the instructions from the beginning until the user chooses to halt the program.
>
> and
>
> 7. When the user wishes to enter no more isotopes, the program should display a list of all the isotopes studied.

I have enjoyed studying python very much, and am having fun learning, a push in the right direction would be great :)

Comment: `print "Oooops, please use numbers only\n"` is Python 2, not Python 3. Python 2 is out of support now, so check to make sure you are learning from resources for the right version.

Comment: You seem to be familiar with the `while True` and `break` concept for prompting users and accepting input. Repeating instructions from the beginning until the user would like to halt is essentially the same idea. In general, it is a better practice to store the user input as a flag and use that flag to determine if the main loop should continue, ie: `while flag:`.   You're final requirement is pretty straightforward. Display all your results. So first, store them in a variable (perhaps in a list?), and when your main loop exists display them.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm using a tricket.io embed on my school website, it seems to run fine, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @h0r53 append them to a list, yes, i shall do that, I've spent almost all day just writing this, the syntax and getting everything just right is tough, let's hope it all clicks together soon,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a school project I'm not posting a complete solution. However, I will help you with the two things you are having issues with. The first thing to do is to create another loop that creates a menu-like application where users can continually enter data. The second is to display a list of results. I've defined two variables to drive this logic. `run` and `results`. Review the logic below and try writing your code where I've stated `# Do your primary logic here...`. In case you aren't familiar with certain syntax, the line `run = selection == "yes"` translates to, *if selection equals yes, then run is true; otherwise false*. You could replace this with a simple if condition, of course.

```
results = []
run = True
while run:
    # Do your primary logic here...


    # Store results in a list...
    results.append("The isotope of {} will have {} grams left after {} seconds".format(isotope, result, iso_ET))

    # 6: The program should then repeat the instructions from the beginning until the user chooses to halt the program.

    selection = input("\n Do you want to calculate another isotopes halflife (yes/no): ")
    run = selection == "yes"


# 7: When the user wishes to enter no more isotopes, the program should display a list of all the isotopes studied.

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

On a seperate note, as someone pointed out in the comments your original code uses Python2 syntax. This is discouraged, as Python2 is officially declared obsolete. Yes, your resources may still provide support for Python2, but as a programmer you should be writting in the current standard, which is Python3. It's better to learn now than to write code that is unusable in the future.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you,  It's a steep hill, but I'm climbing :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function called `main()`, and make a loop like this: 
`while Finished == False:
    loop()`
 and in your main function make a way for the user to quit the program for exemple:

```
a = input("Do you want to quit ?")
if a == "y":
    finished == True
    break
```